# Passing a list of an interface to a function c#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have 2 objects and a mutual interface

```
public interface IMyInterface { ... }
public class MyClass1 : IMyInterface { ... }
public class MyClass2 : IMyInterface { ... }
```

Then I have a function that accepts a list of `IMyInterface`

```
public void MyFunction(List<IMyInterface> myObjects) { ... }
```

If I were to call this function using `List<MyClass1>` or `List<MyClass2>` I get an error saying I cannot convert `List<MyClass1>` to `List<IMyInterface>`, however, if I changed my function signature to -

```
public void MyFunction(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myObjects) { ... }
```

there is no longer an error. My question is why does this work for `IEnumerable` and not a concrete `List`?

Comment: A bas class number properties  <= inherited class number of properties.  Sop you cannot take a class with more properties and cast to a smaller object.  You can take a smaller object a cast to a larger object.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to covariance and contravariance. The problem is that your method might do this:

```
public void AddItem(List<IAnimal> animals)
{
    animals.Add(new Tiger());
    animals.Add(new Giraffe());
}
```

No matter whether the caller passes in a `List<Giraffe>` or `List<Tiger>`, this would end up inserting the wrong type into the list.